# Find the branch points of $\sqrt[3]{z^3-1}$ and describe the Riemann surface of the function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have found my branch points of the function at $z=1, e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}, e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}}$. I know that you can take any branch cut that touches each of the branch points. However, I am utterly lost as to what "describe the Riemann surface" means and what this would look like as a formal write up.

[Here is an image of my solution showing I have decided to answer this question. Any advice on if this is correct or completely wrong would be appreciated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f04ng.png)

Comment: What is the **background** of the problem?  
If the problem is from a contest, which contest?  
If (instead) the problem is from a book &/or class, 
what definitions, theorems or previously (solved) problems has your book or class focused on that you think might be pertinent here?

Comment: Incidentally, I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface.  Unfortunately, my knowledge of complex analysis is not advanced enough to understand the article.

Comment: I'll rephrase @user2661923 : What language from the source of this question is used to define and describe Riemann surfaces.  There are several modes of description and until you are more explicit, there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: @EricTowers The problem is from the Gamelin complex analysis book. We have been given no further instructions and have only covered the material in this book (that is, we've only talked about reimann surfaces in the context of the square root function and the "description" given there seems very loose to me.